# Retrieve input field set value

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5. I have set a default `value` (on form load) to the input field. However, on `form` submission when I try to retrieve this previously assigned default `value`, it returns an empty string.

How can I solve this?

```
<input formControlName="age" type="text" id="ageid"  class="form-item" value="{{student.age}}">
```

This is how I try to retrieve the value as:

```
console.log("result " + JSON.stringify(this.studentform.value.age));
```

update

```
this.studentform = this.fb.group({
  age: ['', Validators.required]
}, { });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using the following code:

```
console.log("result " + JSON.stringify(this.studentform.controls.age.value));
```

Even try by printing the `this.studentform` object to see the state of the controls

Comment: I am reopening this question. It doesn't work. When I set the default value as `0` and try to retrieve using your method I get an empty string.

Comment: Could you post the initialization of the reactive form  in the component ts  please  by updating the original question please.

Comment: I mean when you initialize  `this.studentform` and the control `age`

Comment: did you try with `[(ngModel)]  <input formControlName="age" type="text" id="ageid"  class="form-item" [(ngModel)]="student.age">`